# Which table gets expanded in DAX CALCULATE/SUM?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am new to the concept of table expansion and trying to understand which of the table gets expanded?

For example in the following formula the tableX gets expanded:

Example 1 =
SUMX(tableX, tableX[col1])

However, for the formula examples given below:

Example 2 =
SUMX( VALUES( TABLE1[col1]),
CALCULATE( SUMX(TABLE2, EXPR) ) )

Example 3 =
CALCULATE(SUMX(TABLE2, EXPR), TABLE3[col1]=10)

Example 4 =
CALCULATE(SUMX(TABLE4, EXPR), FILTER(ALL(TABLE5), TABLE5[col1]=10))

Which of the above tables get expanded?

Generally in a DAX formula what is the concept that decides which table gets expanded?

Comment: It will depend on the table relationships. You haven't given enough information to say.

Comment: I'm asking which tables get expanded. I am not asking what the expanded table would look like. So why do you need the table relationships?

Comment: Well, if there are no relationships, there is nothing to expand.

Comment: Just trying to understand which of the tables will attempt an expansion.

Comment: Tables expand along M:1 relationships (from M to 1, but not the other way around). For example, if table1 is a fact, and table 2 is a dimension, connected with M:1 relation, table 1 gets expanded. As a general rule, fact tables get expanded, while dimensions don't unless they are snow-flaked and thus have their own M:1 relations (i.e, Product - Product Category). That's why you need to include relationships description into your question.